# Gaussian Curvature at the point where all curves passing through the point have curvature greater than C

Tags: differential-geometry

Let S be a regular surface and let p $\in$ S. Let $C > 0$ and suppose that every regular curve $ \alpha :(−\epsilon,\epsilon) \rightarrow S$  with $\alpha(0)=p$  has curvature at least C at p. Show that the Gaussian Curvature at p, $K(p) \ge C^{2}$.

Comment: Do you know the relationship between the second fundamental form at $p$ and the curvatures of curves passing through $p$?

Comment: @Anthony Yes. The second fundament form at the point is the normal curvature $k_{n}$, and that $k_{n} = k cos(\theta)$ where k is the curvature of curves through p. My approach was to find bounds on the normal curvature and then conclude by using the fact that Gaussian Curvature $K = k_{1}k_{2}$. But, I can't reach the desired conclusion. Maybe I'm missing something?